# Divorce Rate Probability

Tags: probability

I'm given the following information:

- Couples spending less than $1000 on their wedding have a divorce rate of 24% after 20 years.
- Couples spending more than $20000 have a divorce rate of 73% after 20 years.
- All other couples have a divorce rate of 50%.
- 35% of couples spend less than $1000
- 15% of couples spend more than $20000

From this, I said:

- Let $D$ be the event 'couple gets divorced'
- Let $C$ be the event 'couple spends less than $1000'
- Let $E$ be the event 'couple spends more than $20000'

The probabilities I get from this are:

- Pr$(D|C) = 0.24$
- Pr$(D|E) = 0.73$
- Pr$(D) = 0.5$
- Pr$(C) = 0.35$
- Pr$(E) = 0.15$

Part (a) was to find a couple who spent less than $1000 and are now divorced. For this I did

Pr$(C \land D)$ = Pr$(D,C)$ = Pr$(D|C)$Pr$(C)$ = $0.24 \cdot 0.35$ = $0.084$

So my questions are, is that an appropriate way to find (a), and also, how would I find

- (b) a couple who spent more than $20000 and are not divorced?, and
- (c) a couple who are not divorced.?

Comment: Hahaha, I just read this article a couple of hours ago. It also mentioned the size of the diamond ring, which you seem to have excluded.

Comment: p(D) is not 0.5. The wording was "all other couples have a divorce rate of 50%".